# collect multi inputs in one hidden text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form in html to collect macaddress, and I want to output all the entered data in the (CompleteMacAddress) text value like (10-20-30-40-50-60)

Any help with javascript or jquery?

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="get">
    <input name="MacAddressPart1" type="text" id="MacAddressPart1" size="2" maxlength="2" >
    <input name="MacAddressPart2" type="text" id="MacAddressPart2" size="2" maxlength="2">
    <input name="MacAddressPart3" type="text" id="MacAddressPart3" size="2" maxlength="2">
    <input name="MacAddressPart4" type="text" id="MacAddressPart4" size="2" maxlength="2">
    <input name="MacAddressPart5" type="text" id="MacAddressPart5" size="2" maxlength="2">
    <input name="MacAddressPart6" type="text" id="MacAddressPart6" size="2" maxlength="2">

    <input type="hidden" name="CompleteMacAddress" value="">
```

Comment: `Java`!=`JavaScript`. Please read description of tags you are using if you are not sure which one of them to chose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
$(function() {
    var macSelector = "input[name^='MacAddressPart']";
    $(macSelector).bind('keyup', function() {
        var macs = $.map($(macSelector), function(input) { return $(input).val(); })
        $('input[name="CompleteMacAddress"]').val(macs.join("-"))
    });
});
```

To see it working, [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/PL9xt/2/). Notice that it gets updated as the user types in. ;)

Comment: It won't play nicely with other input elements. Its better to use real ids/classes in selector.

Comment: I know. Since he didn't use classes in first place (in his original's post example) that was my first solution. The author can tweak it to use more suitable selectors, for sure. I strongly advise him to change my example to be more precise.

Comment: Is that a reason to downvote on this solution, btw? Or is it just a plain sabotage in order to make yours shine brighter?

Comment: It wasn't me. I can't give you an upvote though, for two reasons: its not good with other inputs and keyup event occurs way more often than is needed. A simple submit event can do the job fine (your code too).

Comment: Here it goes. I've updated it. Now it uses a better selectors approach.

Comment: Ups, actually have seen it was me. Sorry, meant other answer.

Comment: its working great , but what if i want to use ids or classes instead of :text ??

Answer (score 1):

Give all your html elements proper ids (including the form and hidden input).

```
$("#formID").submit(function(event) {
  $("#hiddenID").value(
    $("#MacAddressPart1").val('00')+"-"+
    $("#MacAddressPart2").val('00')+"-"+
    $("#MacAddressPart3").val('00')+"-"+
    $("#MacAddressPart4").val('00')+"-"+
    $("#MacAddressPart5").val('00')+"-"+
    $("#MacAddressPart6").val('00')
  );   
});
```

Note the `'00'` will cause it to default to 00-00-00-00-00-00 incase there is no value.

Comment: That is not optimal way.

Comment: Because ? Its much more readable than the other proposed solution.

Comment: It's readable, but if one name is changed, the code won't work.

Comment: Cant see your point. Its not better to have something that would catch on all input fields of that form, cause what if he adds some elements there later on and wonder about a malformed mac id which won't be visible at first because they are send hidden. This would be a very hard to spot error, for any other coder than the one who wrote that.

Comment: Well one problem thousands of solutions. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

it would be a lot easier to just use one text field to enter the whole mac and validation the length and characters upon change. Anyway you can get an individual input value with basic javascript --> document.getElementById('MacAddressPart6').value and + to other string values then set value also with getElementById('aaa')=

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
$('[name="form1"]').submit(function() {
    $('[name="CompleteMacAddress"]').val(
        $('[name="MacAddressPart1"]').val() + '-' + 
        $('[name="MacAddressPart2"]').val() + '-' + 
        $('[name="MacAddressPart3"]').val() + '-' + 
        $('[name="MacAddressPart4"]').val() + '-' + 
        $('[name="MacAddressPart5"]').val() + '-' + 
        $('[name="MacAddressPart6"]').val()
    );
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('[name="form1"]').submit(function() {
    $('[name="CompleteMacAddress"]').val($('input[id^="MacAddressPart"]').map(
        function() { return this.value || '00'; }).get().join('-'));
});
```

Comment: That is not optimal way.

Comment: And by optimal you mean...?

Comment: If any name is accidentaly changes, the code won´t work. Instead you can do it more clean, like @Leandro answerd.

Comment: Sure, I thought about that too, but what tells you that these are the only text inputs in his code? `$(':text')` won't suffice. Perhaps `$('[name="form1"]:text')` but still.

Comment: Its totally ok. Could have default values of '00' though. I'd use ids too, because name selector could in theory return multiple objects.. But its ok to use it here too, as long as HTML is fine.

Answer (score 0):

JsFiddle Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/pdLh8/3/

Detect Keyup + update input:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('input[id^="MacAddressPart"]').keyup(
     function () {
         var mac = [];
         $('input[id^="MacAddressPart"]').each(function (index) {
             mac.push($(this).val());
         });
         $("input[name='CompleteMacAddress']").val(mac.join('-'));
     });
 });
```